# NotifyPropertyChanged isn't updating DependencyProperty in CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have made a CustomControl, with the DP `Threshold`, like so:

```
public class SymbolControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThresholdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Threshold", typeof(IThreshold<SolidColorBrush>), typeof(SymbolControl));

    public IThreshold<SolidColorBrush> Threshold
    {
        get { return (IThreshold<SolidColorBrush>)GetValue(ThresholdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThresholdProperty, value);  }
    }
...
}
```

Here is where the Property is used in the `xaml` of the custom control:

```
...
        <Border.Background>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThreshholdToReturnValueConverter}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" >
                <Binding Path="Threshold" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <Binding Path="SymbolValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <Binding Path="DefaultBackground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Background>
...
```

And here is How the CustomControl is used:

```
<controls:SymbolControl ... Threshold="{Binding Threshold, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}}" .../>
```

When I call `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Threshold))`, the CustomControl does not update.

However I have placed a dummy converter, with a breakpoint in, in the Threshold binding when the custom control is instantiated and this breakpoint triggers when I call `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Threshold))`, so it appears the binding isn't updating the target?

I have also tried adding a `PropertyChangedCallback` for the DP `ThresholdProperty` with a breakpoint in which only triggers when the original property is first instantiated.

I have also found doing this in the ViewModel causes the custom control to update:

```
var temp = Threshold;
Threshold = null;
Threshold = temp;
```

I have done lots of searching online and had no luck, any ideas of what the problem could be?

Comment: The Threshold dependency property ignores any updates as long as you do not replace its value by a new `IThreshold<SolidColorBrush>` instance, i.e. `{Binding Threshold}` provides a different object (or null). This is by design.

Comment: @Clemens Oh I had no idea, is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: Yes, by doing what you alread did, i.e. set a temporary null value.

Comment: The problem with this is I can't find a way to execute that bit of code if one of the properties with in the `IThreshold<SolidColorBrush>` instance change, I have tried adding it to the `PropertyChanged` event like `_threshold.PropertyChanged += Threshold_PropertyChanged;` (where `void Threshold_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)` sets it temporarily to null) in the setter, but this does not work as it will asign itself to null so the last line (`Threshold = temp;`) will not execute

Comment: You may change your MultiBinding (and its Converter) so that it binds to the individual properties of a Threshold, e.g. `<Binding Path="Threshold.SomeValue" .../>`. Of course these properties must also fire the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Alfie: What's the purpose of the `IThreshold` interface? Why can't you use a `Brush` property that you set to a new `Brush` object whenever you want to update the property? You may of course also assing the current property a new instance of an `IThreshold<SolidColorBrush>` to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found another work around as I was unable to use the other work around given in the question:

I added the code into `Threshold.cs`:

```
public Threshold : IThreshold<SolidColorBrush>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...
    public Threshold()
    {
        ...
        this.PropertyChanged += delegate (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) { if (e.PropertyName != nameof(WorkAround)) { NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(WorkAround)); } };
    }
...
public bool WorkAround { set; get; }
}
```

In the `xaml` of the custom control I added the 4th binding to the `MultiBinding`:

```
...
        <Border.Background>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThreshholdToReturnValueConverter}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" >
                <Binding Path="Threshold" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <Binding Path="SymbolValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <Binding Path="DefaultBackground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <Binding Path="Threshold.WorkAround" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Background>
...
```

However this workaround is not ideal, so I will not accept it, if anyone finds a better solution please let me know :)